# Why are there such high levels of API calls from Marketing Cloud to Salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, limits

The user that integrates Marketing Cloud to Salesforce has been using 20000 API calls per day for a long time. I'm not happy about that but today it used 39,000+ API calls in a morning.

This has blocked revenue generating activities that we have over API.

*Why does the MC user cause such a high level of access*? The MC admin says that the access should happen Once per 15 minutes but I see 1500 access per day, sometimes many times per minute.

Answer (score 1):

Are you not using Marketing Cloud connect? API calls to SF don't count towards any limits if you are.

Assuming you aren't using the connector, the calls can ramp up pretty quickly eg. Sync 6 objects every 15 mins is 24 calls per hour possibly more. Also if tracking data is getting sent back to SF high volume of sends could very easily increase those calls. There could be several other contributing factors here too.

Comment: Yes - but it uses a dedicated user license: it is this user license that is making the API calls. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/marketing-cloud-connect/install-mc-connect

Answer (score 1):

You must make sure you have upgraded to Connected App integration as per this article? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_upgrade_to_connected_app_authentication.htm&type=5

API calls made here do not count towards your API limits

Comment: I don't know - I will look.

Comment: Yes we have used the Connected App.

Comment: I will suggest you reach out to SF support, as this doesn’t seem to  correspond with general documentation

Comment: @SeanGorman - did you have any luck identifying the root cause?

Comment: Not yet - I have a case with support but...